# Objective-c, passing NSURLConnection result to a View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns, nsurlconnection

Long time reader, first time poster here.

I'm creating a test app that creates a NSURLConnection and then displays the result on an UILabel.

I am presently using a Notification Center observer, which fires a notification from within connectionDidFinishLoading to wait for the connection to complete successfully, before I look for the result.

However, what I am struggling to conceptualize is where to store the response data so that I can access it from my View Controller and post the result to the UILabel. (Or from anywhere other than an instance of my Connection Class, for that matter.)

I don't want to post directly to the UILabel from connectionDidFinishLoading. I need a way to decide what I will do with the response later - so my Connection Class stays generalized.

I need a better way to save the response data somewhere, where I can reference it after the instance of the Connection Class has terminated.

Ideally, it should be somewhere that I can have multiple instances of the Connection Class open, and access each response in turn as I need them. This eliminates the potential to just create a variable in my View Controller or somewhere else more global and dump the response to it.

Any ideas on what design patterns could/should be used here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: NSMutableDictionary, NSMutableArray are primary storage options. But it depends alot on what data u r storing. For ur reference some complex architecture apps uses core data in conjunction with sqlite to store data.

Comment: Try setting it int the NSNotification's `userInfo` dictionary!

Comment: @H2CO3 - `userInfo` worked perfectly, I don't know how I missed that feature. Thanks!

Comment: Damn, why didn't I post it as an aswer... Anyway, I'm glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions for you to start with are :

1. Make a singleton class. I will have a property NSDictionary * info or NSArray *infoList; You will have acces to the same data from wherever the app. Update the property, post the notification, access the property from the viewController.
2. Store the info into a plist/file. Serialize the information, or save plain stream. Whatever you like.Thus after you finish writing to the file, post the notification, read from the file from anyplace within the app.

In both cases if you want multiple connections i suggest going for the factory design Pattern.

Comment: As I noted in my comment above, for this test app I'm using `userInfo` (which I was previously unaware of). However, I may move to the singleton class suggestion once I've expanded functionality more - that way I can add a lot more custom logic.